# Keeping IE Open

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-8

I would like to create a Powershell script that will re-open IE each time it is closed.

```
Do {
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate(www.google.com)
$ie.Visible = $true
   }
While (?)
```

I plan on using Start-Sleep to give the application time to fully open and so it doesn't keep spawning processes like mad, but I haven't been able to find out which value links to finding out if the window has been closed.  Perhaps I'm going about this wrong.

Comment: If I ever had to use a computer that did this I would kill myself, just saying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure windows has functions somewhere which can hook process creation and destruction.  You could maintain a count of internet explorer processes running, and start a new one if the count reaches zero.  No idea how to do it with pure powershell though.

Comment: I'm reinventing the kiosk wheel kinda... the webpage that will be visited doesn't have a log out option so we have to close it for the next person to use hence the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(){Start iexplore www.stackoverflow.com -wait}`

Answer (score 0):

I have used the windows perfmon for this before. You use the Perfmon alerts to check countof ie instances running, and if they go below 1, start one.

It was many years ago and I have not used this recently.